# Webpack doesn't create react build production version

Tags: reactjs, webpack, production

I have the following `webpack-production.config.js` file:

```
/* jshint node: true */
var webpack = require('webpack');
process.env.NODE_ENV = JSON.stringify('production');
module.exports = {
    watch: false,
    entry: {
        index: './client/js/index.js', 
        article: './client/js/article.js', 
        error: './client/js/error.js'
    },
    output: {
        filename: '[name].bundle.js'
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            // JSON
            { test: /\.json$/, loader: "json-loader" },
            // React & ES2015
            {
                test: /.jsx?$/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                query: {
                    presets: ['react', 'es2015']
                },
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            'process.env': {
                NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify('production')
            }
        }),
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
            compress: { warnings: false }
        })
    ]
};
```

When I run this task using the command `webpack --config webpack-production.config.js` the bundle files are generated but when I open my site in brawser the React devtool extensions says: `This page is using the development build of React.`.

What is wrong in my config file? How can I generate the `React` production version?

I mention that the official site of `React` says that I have to use the above  two plugins and it should be enough.

**UPDATED**

I added the `path` option in `output` settings and now I have the following error
in the braoser console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '_' of undefined
```

I mention that I use `underscore` like this:

```
import _ from 'underscore'
```

Comment: any special purpose for convert to json?

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that this is the cause:

```
process.env.NODE_ENV = JSON.stringify('production');
```

It should be:

```
process.env.NODE_ENV = 'production';
```

Alternatively, you can use the Webpack `-p` command line option that sets the `NODE_ENV` environment variable to `production`.